# Some Issue in SeekBar

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

I am using `seekbar` with `MediaPlayer`.For `seekbar` progress I am using `AsyncTask`,
I am using setMax and progress in Miliseconds so that the progress is smooth.
I am facing some issue while I am changing `seekBar` manually while Playing `video`.

**SeekBar**

```
max = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
mSeekBar.setMax(max);
```

Here is **SeekBarTask**

```
public class SeekBarTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        while (!isCancelled() && mediaPlayer != null && isPlaying) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
                publishProgress();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        cancel(true);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            if (mSeekBar != null) {
                mSeekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            }
            if (currentTimeText != null) {
                currentTimeText.setText(convertToTimeFormat(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
            }
        }
    }
```

SeekbarChnageListner

```
SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener mSeekBarChangeListener = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        if (fromUser) {
            Debug.d(TAG, "onProgressChanged : Progress = " + progress + " fromUser = " + fromUser);

                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                    currentTimeText.setText(convertToTimeFormat(progress));
                }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
};
```

Here is the logs for the same

```html
02-04 12:33:02.702 26960-26960/sampleApp D/VideoPlayerFragment: onProgressUpdate-- seekBarPosition7990
02-04 12:33:02.716 26960-26960/sampleApp D/VideoPlayerFragment: onProgressUpdate-- seekBarPosition8003
02-04 12:33:02.721 26960-26960/sampleApp D/VideoPlayerFragment: onProgressChanged : Progress = 16140 fromUser = true
02-04 12:33:02.732 26960-26960/sampleApp D/VideoPlayerFragment: onProgressUpdate-- seekBarPosition16140
02-04 12:33:02.734 26960-26960/sampleApp D/VideoPlayerFragment: onProgressUpdate-- seekBarPosition16140
02-04 12:33:02.751 26960-26960/sampleApp D/VideoPlayerFragment: onProgressUpdate-- seekBarPosition4
02-04 12:33:02.754 26960-26960/sampleApp D/VideoPlayerFragment: onProgressUpdate-- seekBarPosition7
02-04 12:33:02.771 26960-26960/sampleApp D/VideoPlayerFragment: onProgressUpdate-- seekBarPosition24
02-04 12:33:02.774 26960-26960/sampleApp D/VideoPlayerFragment: onProgressUpdate-- seekBarPosition27
02-04 12:33:02.782 26960-26960/sampleApp D/VideoPlayerFragment: onProgressUpdate-- seekBarPosition35
02-04 12:33:02.802 26960-26960/sampleApp D/VideoPlayerFragment: onProgressUpdate-- seekBarPosition55
02-04 12:33:02.804 26960-26960/sampleApp D/VideoPlayerFragment: onProgressUpdate-- seekBarPosition57
02-04 12:33:02.816 26960-26960/sampleApp D/VideoPlayerFragment: onProgressUpdate-- seekBarPosition69
02-04 12:33:02.835 26960-26960/sampleApp D/VideoPlayerFragment: onProgressUpdate-- seekBarPosition85
02-04 12:33:02.838 26960-26960/sampleApp D/VideoPlayerFragment: onProgressUpdate-- seekBarPosition91
02-04 12:33:02.848 26960-26960/sampleApp D/VideoPlayerFragment: onProgressUpdate-- seekBarPosition101
02-04 12:33:02.865 26960-26960/sampleApp D/VideoPlayerFragment: onProgressUpdate-- seekBarPosition118
02-04 12:33:02.868 26960-26960/sampleApp D/VideoPlayerFragment: onProgressUpdate-- seekBarPosition121
02-04 12:33:02.885 26960-26960/sampleApp D/VideoPlayerFragment: onProgressUpdate-- seekBarPosition138
02-04 12:33:02.887 26960-26960/sampleApp D/VideoPlayerFragment: onProgressUpdate-- seekBarPosition140
02-04 12:33:02.899 26960-26960/sampleApp D/VideoPlayerFragment: onProgressUpdate-- seekBarPosition152
02-04 12:33:02.916 26960-26960/sampleApp D/VideoPlayerFragment: onProgressUpdate-- seekBarPosition169
02-04 12:33:02.932 26960-26960/sampleApp D/VideoPlayerFragment: onProgressUpdate-- seekBarPosition184
```

Can some one tell where I am making mistake. When I am touching the seekBar, the seekbar changes to some very less value, which i have attached in the logs.

Comment: What is the max value of your SeekBar? By default, the SeekBar is divided into 100 steps. In short this means that you will have to calculate the progress in percent, or change the max-setting of your SeekBar to match the maximum number of milliseconds the video lasts.

Do you know how long the video lasts? If so, the progress should be set to: `(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / <total videolength in milliseconds>) * 100`. Then you will have the progress in percent, and you are able to use the SeekBar without altering its max setting.

Comment: offset is of value 120, I am using it for some other purpose. Without offset also I am facing this issue. I just removed that. Please ignore that.

Comment: @jaolstad - I have done setMax at the time of initialization of seekbar. I have added that code also here.

Comment: In `onProgressChanged()`, store the current progress/position in a global variable. 

Move this part of the code 

`if (mediaPlayer != null) {
  mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
}` 

to the `onStopTrackingTouch()` method, and replace `mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress)` with `mediaPlayer.seekTo(<newglobalvariable>)`.

Comment: `Thread.sleep(10);` are you aware it will make updates more or less 100 times per second?

Comment: @pskink - yes Thead.sleep with 100 and 10 is almost the same. And the issue is not due to this. I checked this one.

Comment: why do you want to have the seekbar position with resolution == 1ms? isn't one second or 1/10 sec accurate enough?

Comment: with resolution of 1 ms the scrolling is very smooth continuous